# Delete array in the array using httpClient in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem.
I have service `DataStorageServiceService`, and in this service I have 2 method, `deleteCategory` and `deleteProduct`. I have component `AdminComponent` from his I want to delete product and category on server. Structure on my server is :

```
{
                id: 1, name: 'Mr.', description: 'dasdad', image: "sada", products: [
                    { id: 0, name: 'Milos', description: "sdada", numberOfProduct: 1, image: 'ssad' },
                ]



            },
            {
                id: 2, name: 'Misko', description: 'dasdad', image: "sada", products: [
                    { id: 0, name: 'Milos', description: "sdada", numberOfProduct: 1, image: 'ssad' },
                    { id: 1, name: 'Somi', description: "haha", numberOfProduct: 1, image: 'haha' }
                ]
            }
```

My delete `deleteCategory` method work fine but my `deleteProduct` do now work very good, and do not delete product on the server.

This is my `deleteCategory` method:

```
 deleteCategory(product: CategoryModel | number): Observable<CategoryModel> {
    const id = typeof product === 'number' ? product : product.id;
    const url = `${this.cateogryUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.delete<CategoryModel>(url, httpOptions).pipe(

      catchError(this.handleError<CategoryModel>('deleteProduct'))
    );
  }
```

This is my `deleteProduct` method:

```
 deleteProduct(product: ProductModel | number, index:number): Observable<ProductModel> {
    const idCategory = typeof product === 'number' ? product : product.id;
    const id = index;

const url = `${this.cateogryUrl}/${id}/${idCategory}`;

    return this.http.delete<ProductModel>(url, httpOptions).pipe(

      catchError(this.handleError<ProductModel>('deleteProduct'))
    );


}
```

My method for deleting in my component is:

```
deteleProduct(indexCategory: number, indexProduct: number, category: ProductModel) {
    this.dataStorageServiceService.deleteProduct(category,indexProduct).subscribe()
    this.categoryList[indexCategory].products.splice(indexProduct, 1);

  }

  deteleCategory(indexProduct: number, category: CategoryModel) {
    this.dataStorageServiceService.deleteCategory(category).subscribe();
    this.categoryList.splice(indexProduct, 1);

  }
```

Do anyone know why I can not delete products on the ser

Comment: Hmm ok... you gave us code for your client side, but no code for your server side and what technology/framework you are using for your server side. At this point, no one knows the answer.

Comment: Hm, I using `InMemoryDataService` package, this simulates backend.

Comment: Ok. Well one thing stands out is your `deteleProduct` method. Your `this.dataStorageServiceService.deleteProduct()` is `async` an observable stream. So you need to wrap your `splice` inside your subscribe callback.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand what I should to do?
Can you give me some examples?

Comment: [rxjs doc](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) although it's for v4, it is still the same for v6+ in terms of syntax wise.

Comment: If I understand  you opinion is the `this.categoryList[indexCategory].products.splice(indexProduct, 1);` should set in my observable ?